# Cumbersome inheritance from template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Below is the code for a template with some functionality. Several structures will inherit from it, and each structure will use a different UniqueTag. That is, each structure inherits from a unique template. With the naive attempt #1, the code becomes very verbose. Attempt #2 is a bit better in regards to verbosity, but removes the desired property of being able to change the UniqueTag value with template instantiation. The macro version at #3 hardly makes it any better.

I am certainly no c++ syntax guru, which makes me wonder: **Can this be expressed more clearly?**

**Attempt #1**

```
template <int UniqueTag, typename Verbose, typename Arguments>
struct Base {
    static const int tag = UniqueTag;
    // Random example functionality
    float data_;
    Base(float data) : data_(data) {}
    int do_stuff(Verbose& v, Arguments& a) {
        return v + a;
    }
};

template <int UniqueTag, typename Verbose, typename Arguments> // once...
struct Foo : Base<UniqueTag, Verbose, Arguments> { // twice...
    typedef Base<UniqueTag, Verbose, Arguments> base_t; // thrice..!
    Foo(float data) : base_t(data) {}
    int do_it() {
        Verbose v(10);
        Arguments a(10);
        return base_t::do_stuff(v, a); // must qualify dependent class name
    }
};
```

**Attempt #2**

A slightly more sane approach is to store the template arguments in the base class. Now `Foo` doesn't have to be a template class. It can inherit from the template and refer to the types through it, without the dependent class issue. **It does however take away the template-ness of `Foo2`, which is not acceptable.**

```
template <int UniqueTag, typename Verbose, typename Arguments>
struct Base2 {
    typedef Verbose verbose_t;
    typedef Arguments arguments_t;
    static const int tag = UniqueTag;
    float data_;
    Base2(float data) : data_(data) {}
    int do_stuff(Verbose& v, Arguments& a) {
        return v + a;
    }
};

typedef Base2<1, int, int> Foo2Base;
struct Foo2 : Foo2Base {
    Foo2(float data) : Foo2Base(data) {}
    int do_it() {
        verbose_t v(10);
        arguments_t a(10);
        return do_stuff(v, a);
    }
};
```

**Attempt #3**

A macro version of the previous example also possible, but it saves a mere one line while making the code less obvious.

```
#define BASE_MACRO(name, tag, typeA, typeB) \
    typedef Base2<tag, typeA, typeB> name ## Base; \
    struct name : name ## Base

BASE_MACRO(Foo3, 2, int, int) {
    Foo3(float data) : Foo3Base(data) {}
    int do_it() {
        verbose_t v(10);
        arguments_t a(10);
        return do_stuff(v, a);
    }
};

// To compile all of the above.
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Foo<0, int, int> a(1.0);
    std::cout << a.do_it() << std::endl;
    Foo2 b(1.0);
    std::cout << b.do_it() << std::endl;
    Foo3 c(1.0);
    std::cout << c.do_it() << std::endl;
};
```

Even a definite "There are no ways to express this in a better way" would be helpful if that is the case.

Comment: I don't know of a better way than those in the question.

Answer (score 1):

What about?

making do_stuff a template method

```
template <int UniqueTag>
struct Base {
    static const int tag = UniqueTag;
    // Random example functionality
    float data_;
    Base(float data) : data_(data) {}
    template <typename Verbose, typename Arguments>
    int do_stuff(Verbose& v, Arguments& a) {
        return v + a;
    }
};

template <int UniqueTag, typename Verbose, typename Arguments> // once...
struct Foo : Base<UniqueTag> { // shorter reference
    typedef Base<UniqueTag> base_t; // shorter reference
    Foo(float data) : base_t(data) {}
    int do_it() {
        Verbose v(10);
        Arguments a(10);
        return base_t::do_stuff(v, a); // must qualify dependent class name
    }
};
```

Keeps the template-ness of Foo, while reducing the verbosity

Comment: I like it. It made me fiddle around a bit more, and I came up with something else that may work with/without this approach.

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling around, I came up with my own simplification. Just pass the entire base as a single template argument.

```
template <int UniqueTag, typename Verbose, typename Arguments>
struct Base {
    typedef Verbose verbose_t;
    typedef Arguments arguments_t;
    static const int tag = UniqueTag;
    float data_;
    Base2(float data) : data_(data) {}
    int do_stuff(Verbose& v, Arguments& a) {
        return v + a;
    }
};

template <typename Base>
struct Foo : Base {
    Foo(float data) : Base(data) {}
    int do_it() {
        typename Base::verbose_t v(10);
        typename Base::arguments_t a(10);
        return this->do_stuff(v, a);
    }
};

Foo<Base<5, int, int> > f(1.0);
```

Optionally combined with @jsantander's answer, it should help in various situations.